# Run lighthouse inside Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, lighthouse

I am trying to run [Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) inside a Cloud Function.
I have copied the simplest example from the [README.md](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/readme.md) and added `'--headless'` option.

However, I am getting this error:

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
The environment variable CHROME_PATH must be set to executable of a build of Chromium version 54.0 or later.
```

How is it possible to do such a thing in Cloud Function?

This is the code I am uploading to the Cloud Function:

```
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

function launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(url, opts, config = null) {
  return chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: opts.chromeFlags}).then(chrome => {
    opts.port = chrome.port;
    return lighthouse(url, opts, config).then(results => {
      return chrome.kill().then(() => results.lhr)
    });
  });
}

const opts = {
  chromeFlags: ['--show-paint-rects','--headless']
};

exports.hello = async (req,res) => {
  const results = await launchChromeAndRunLighthouse('https://www.google.com',opts);
  // res.send(results);
}
```

Comment: you might want to check this: simoahava.com/google-cloud/lighthouse-bigquery-google-cloud-platform/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it will not be possible to use Lighthouse on its own since it requires that env var to be set to find an existing Chrome executable.  I suggest looking into a combination of [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) for windowless (headless) Chrome, and using Lighthouse with that.

Puppeteer is known to work on Cloud Functions, and you should be able to find out about that using a web search.

As for combining the two, it looks like there is a library that combines them both already, so I would give that a try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-lighthouse-puppeteer